# Find value of $AB$

Tags: trigonometry

> Let
> $$A=\dfrac{1}{\sin20^\circ\cos40^\circ}+\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}\cos20^\circ\cos40^\circ}$$
> and
> $$B=\cot40^\circ+\cot230^\circ-\tan185^\circ(\tan230^\circ-\cot50^\circ)$$
> Find $AB$.

My attempt :
\begin{align*}
A&=\dfrac{1}{\cos40^\circ}(\dfrac{1}{\sin20^\circ}+\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}\cos20^\circ})\\
&=\dfrac{2(\sqrt{3}\cos20^\circ+\sin20^\circ)}{\sqrt{3}\cos^2 40^\circ}\\
B&=\tan50^\circ(1-\tan5^\circ)+\tan40^\circ(1+\tan5^\circ)
\end{align*}
I tried to factor $A$ and $B$ because I think it will cancel each other out.

Comment: Your $A$ is wrong. $\left(\dfrac{1}{\sin20^\circ}+\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}\cos20^\circ}\right)
=\dfrac{2(\sqrt{3}\cos20^\circ+\sin20^\circ)}{\sqrt{3}\color{blue}\sin 40^\circ}$

Answer (score -1):

\begin{align*}
A &= \frac{4(\sin 60^{\circ} \cos 20^{\circ} + \cos 60^{\circ} \sin 20^{\circ})}{\sqrt{3} \sin 40^{\circ}\cos 40^{\circ}} = \frac{4\sin 80^{\circ}}{\sqrt{3} \sin 40^{\circ}\cos 40^{\circ}} \\&= \frac{8\sin 80^{\circ}}{\sqrt{3}\sin 80^{\circ}} = \frac{8\sqrt{3}}{3}\\
B &= \cot 40^{\circ} + \cot 230^{\circ} - \tan 185^{\circ}(\tan 230^{\circ} - \cot 50^{\circ})  \\ &=\cot 40^{\circ} + \tan 40^{\circ} - \tan 5^{\circ}(\tan 50^{\circ} - \cot 50^{\circ}) \\ &= \cot 40^{\circ} + \tan 40^{\circ} - \tan 5^{\circ}(\cot 40^{\circ} - \tan 40^{\circ})\\
\therefore AB \tan 40^{\circ} &=\frac{8\sqrt{3}}{3} \left ( 1 +\tan^{2} 40^{\circ} - \tan 5^{\circ} ( 1 - \tan^{2} 40^{\circ}) \right ) \\&= \frac{8\sqrt{3}}{3} \left ( 1 +\tan^{2} 40^{\circ} - (\frac{1- \tan 40^{\circ}}{1 + \tan 40^{\circ}}) ( 1 - \tan^{2} 40^{\circ}) \right ) \\ &= \frac{8\sqrt{3}}{3} \left ( 1 +\tan^{2} 40^{\circ} -  ( 1 - \tan 40^{\circ})^{2} \right ) \\ &= \frac{16\sqrt{3}}{3} \tan 40^{\circ}
\end{align*}

Comment: Isn't $A= \frac{2(\sin 60^{\circ} \cos 20^{\circ} + \cos 60^{\circ} \sin 20^{\circ})}{\sqrt{3} \sin 40^{\circ}\cos 40^{\circ}}$ ?